# How to Map Twitter follower/following type of relation in EF Core 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-5.0

How do you configure something similar to Twitter Following and Follower type of relationship using EF Core 5 with the Fluent API? I tried various different ways of configuring it and the only few ways I was able to get it to work is if I ignored the navigation properties on the User entity. I am currently migrating my code from EF Core 2.1 to 5. The following configuration worked earlier. (Not sure if it is misconfigured)

```
    public class User
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<UserFollower> Followers { get; set; }

        public ICollection<UserFollower> Following { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserFollower
    {
        public long UserId { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }

        public long FollowedById { get; set; }

        public User FollowedBy { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserFollowerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserFollower>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserFollower> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(p => new { p.UserId, p.FollowedById });
            builder.HasOne(p => p.User)
                .WithMany(i => i.Followers)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.UserId);
            builder.HasOne(p => p.FollowedBy)
                .WithMany(i => i.Following)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.FollowedById);
        }
    }
```

This configuration throws an error when saving to the database.

```
SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_UserFollower'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserFollower'. The duplicate key value is (111, 111).
```

Even when trying to directly add to the DbContext and calling `SaveChanges()` on it.

`Context.Add(new UserFollower() {UserId = 222, FollowedById = 111});`

What is the recommended way of mapping such a relationship with EF Core 5? Note that I do need to access the UserFollowers table without going through the Navigation properties of the User.

Edit #1

The following is the `OnModelCreating()` for the DbContext

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.ApplyConfigurations(typeof(DbContext).Assembly);
        
        /*few configurations unrelated to UserFollower entity*/
    }
```

User entity has the following configuration,

```
    builder.HasKey(i => i.Id);
    builder.Property(i => i.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Comment: The configuration is ok. Apparently you are doing something wrong when applying (not sure what) changes - you'd better show that code.

Comment: Code is completely fine. It seems that problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have updated the question with the configuration applying code.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring it like this.

```
builder.Entity<User>().HasMany(s => s.Followers)
    .WithOne(f => f.FollowedBy);
builder.Entity<User>().HasMany(s => s.Following)
    .WithOne(f => f.);
```

Also, The PK is missing for the `UserFollower` table, I don't know if an Id is being generated somehow somewhere. If not, maybe this is why it's trying to wrongly use `FollowedById` as key, but define an Id for the `UserFollower` table and see.

```
public class UserFollower
{
    public long Id {get;set;} 

    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public long FollowedById { get; set; }

    public User FollowedBy { get; set; }
 }
```

Even if this works, I would recommend you change the structure of your model, it looks ambigous for the twitter requirements you described. If I query `Userfollowers`

```
var userFollowers = _context.UserFollowers.ToList();
```

For each result in the list, there is no way for me to tell if the user is following or being followed. You could change your models to these ones;

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserFollower> Followers { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserFollowing> Following { get; set; }
}

public class UserFollower
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public long UserFollowingMeId { get; set; }

    public User UserFollowingMe { get; set; }
}
public class UserFollowing
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public long UserIAmFollowingId { get; set; }

    public User UserIAmFollowing { get; set; }
}
```

This way, everybody knows when they check the `UserFollowings` table, the `UserId` is the Id of the person that is following and vice versa for the `UserFollowers` table. If I had an Id of 8 in the system, I can query my followers and people I follow like this;

```
var myFollowers = _context.UserFollowers.Where(UserId = 8);
var peopleIFollow = _context.UserFollowing.Where(UserId = 8);
```

Comment: UserFollower does have a composite primary key. Not sure if having 2 separate tables to store the same information is the solution here.

Comment: @JudeVajiraGunasekera Did you try the configuration in the first part of the answer? And I never said the 2nd part was the solution to your problem. I only said it would be the a better way to do the kind of following-follower requirement because if I looked at the current state of your UserFollower table, I couldn't tell if user in column `FollowedBy` is a user I follow or a user following me.

Comment: yes I have tried the configuring it from the User entity side just like you have mentioned, still it ends messing up the values on ```SaveChanges()``` just like in the question. Yeah I agree, the naming can be confusing at a glance.

Comment: There's a chance you already have a record in the UserFollower table with `UserId = 111` and `FollowedById = 111`. Then you're now trying to create a new record with the same values, duplicate. Since you don't have a traditional primary key, there's no way for the database to know the difference, it just tries to create another (111, 111) composite key, and the duplicate error is thrown. Try add a primary key and see

Comment: It shouldn't give an Error saying (111,111) key conflict when I am trying to add (222,111). yes the conflict comes because even the previous time I tried to add it had added (111,111) instead of (222,111)